# How to maintain a maven project with quartz-1.8.6 and quartz-2.x?

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, quartz-scheduler

I need to use both quartz-1.8.6 and quartz-2.x.x dependencies in the same maven 3 project. 
The reason for keeping 1.8.6 is that it's used by a large amount of code and new features are considered to written in spring, and in this case quartz-2.x come into play.

So the question is: how can I keep both these dependencies in the same project ? Maybe add some exclusions?

Comment: do you really need to use both of them at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you really need to use both of them at the same time

generally the classes may be deprecated. but usage will still be allowed.
You see whole idea of using maven is to avoid multiple jar of same API.

I will suggest code changes and completely using quartz 2.x API.

I was getting similar issue when I used lucene and was switching from 2.2 to 2.8/3, there were not just deprecated methods but many lucene classes were removed i the 2.8 API. I still ended in upgrading the API than using duplicate dependent jars